# CartoDB - Non-animated heatmap, but won't let me layer under

Tags: carto, layers, heat-map, animation

I have a simple heatmap layer that is not animated. I want to move a choropleth layer above that heatmap layer, but Carto will not let me, as it thinks my Heatmap layer is animated.

Is there any way I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Heatmaps (`PIXEL` aggregation) and Torque (`ANIMATED` aggregation) layers always are placed on top of the rest of the layers. So, unfortunately, you cannot put a choropleth layer on top of a heatmap layer at the moment.